# JBoss: get know the listening port

Tags: jboss

Sorry for a silly question. I am starting JBoss for a first time. I need to know what is happening.
I started server on my linux machine with command:

```
 ./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=127.0.0.1 -Djboss.bind.address.management=127.0.0.1&
```

This is what I see in terminal right now:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/local/share/jboss

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true

=========================================================================

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
13:46:46,874 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.2.2.Final-redhat-1
13:46:47,032 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
13:46:47,090 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.1.1.GA (AS 7.2.1.Final-redhat-10) starting
```

The silly question is: which port I should try to find JBoss there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default port is 8080 for web applications. Admin web console is on 9990

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, no any other logs. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the log file is in standalone/log/server.log does it provide more info?

Comment: nope, there is no any errors, just expanded info about started server

Comment: seems i doesn't know host or port, weird issue

Comment: did you start JBoss using sudo ?

Comment: thanks. non-sudo execution and ampersand at the end of line made me blind. now I see starting page at 8080